# What is the logical relationship between the components of IBM MQ?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am using IBM MQ and Java client application in my current assignment.

I would like to know the logical relationship between IBM MQ components like queuemanager, queue, channel, and listener

Types of channel and their practical usage.

Would like to know about how queuemanager handles queues , channels and how listner listens for requests and forwards them to queue manager. Also it will be great if one explains flow between client application-mq queue manager and also the flow between two queue managers in mq hosted on two different machines

Thanks,
Sagar

Comment: I would suggest going to IBM's site.   This is a good resource: https://developer.ibm.com/components/ibm-mq/series/badge-ibm-mq-developer-essentials/

Answer (score 2):

Very broadly, a queue manager is a message broker -- it's a piece of software that hosts queues, etc. A queue manager is a thing you can start and stop. There can, in principle, be multiple queue managers on the same physical host.

A queue is a named location which clients produce data to, and consume data from. This data is broadly referred to as messages. Each queue will belong to a specific queue manager.

A channel is a connection definition -- it specifies the low-level parameters for communication between the client and the queue manager. These parameters include things like encryption methods.

You ask about types of channel, but I suspect that the only type relevant to a Java programmer is the standard message channel, for which the IBM Classes For Java libraries provide a JMS interface. More recent MQ installations also have an AMQP channel which could, in principle, be used with an AMQP JMS library like Apache Qpid-JMS. However, I've never used the AMQP channel, and I'm not convinced it is widely used at present.

A listener is a process that waits for connections from a client, and assigns them to the relevant queue manager.

This is a huge oversimplification, however.

Incidentally, many Java developers seem to struggle with IBM MQ because it pre-dates Java, and is described in a terminology that seems archaic. Java developers who have *no* exposure to messaging middleware might (maybe) benefit from getting started with a messaging application like Apache ActiveMQ, that was designed for Java from the start. ActiveMQ concepts map reasonably easily onto MQ concepts, once the basic principles are understood.